# How to read content of google document

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have used https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads and I have a working copy of code which can download the file from Google drive with permission access.

Is there any way I can read the word document (created using gdrive-New- New Doc)

Sample code to download a file:

```
private static void DownloadFile(string fileId, DriveService driveService)
{

    var request = driveService.Files.Export(fileId, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
    var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
    // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
    // download is completed or failed.
    request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
            (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
            {
                switch (progress.Status)
                {
                    case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                            break;
                        }
                    case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                            break;
                        }
                }
            };


    request.Download(stream);

    using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.doc", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        stream.WriteTo(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a true DOC file then you can get the text using

[Code7248.word_reader](https://sourceforge.net/p/word-reader/wiki/Home/)

```
private string readFileContent(string pDocPath)
{
   if(!System.IO.File.Exists(pDocPath))
   {
       Console.WriteLine("The file doesn't exist");
       return String.Empty;
   }

   var extractor = new TextExtractor(pDocPath);
   var txt = extractor.ExtractText();
   Console.WriteLine(txt);
   return txt;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{       
   var strDocPath = @"C:\Temp\yourWordDoc.doc";
   var strDocTxt = readFileContent(strDocPath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I want to read the document from drive directly with out downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check these two ways to [open files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open) in Google Drive UI:

> The Open with contextual menu item

- Call `files.get` to check the user's permissions for a document, fetch the metadata and download the file content. If a file is created with a Google Doc MIME type, open and convert Google Docs to its supported format.

> The Google Picker dialog for opening files

- Applications can display a file picker to select content from within the app itself. See the [files picker guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/picker) for additional details.